# how to make the .htaccess rule work for specified domain ,subdomain or addons

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my cpanel directory structure:

```
public_html
    |--->wordpress installed 

sudomain-directory
    |--->wordpress installed
addon-domain
    |--->wordpress installed
```

**What I have done:**
Based on user choice the **passwd** and **.htaccess** file will be created to respective domains inside **wp-admin** directory

***.htaccess file***

```
authname "member only"
authtype basic
authuserfile /home/taragurung/public_html/wp-admin/.passfile
require valid-user
```

Now when user try to access ***www.somedomain.com/wp-admin*** the authentication will pop up and it works as expected.

**Problem:**
The problem is it works only for wp-admin but not for the ***www.somedomain.com/wp-login***

> To make it work I added the `<FilesMatch "wp-login.php">` rule and
>   created the .htaccess in the root directory

but doing so will make the rule apply to all the domains and subdomains

**Why I didn't put it in root directory:**
I don't want the rules to be implemented on all the subdomains and addon domains. Want it to be implemented on only those domains or sub-domain user choose to.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood your question correctly - but you only want the authentication to work if the user directs from a specific domain.

To do this you can use an `if directive`.

So, if `user x` comes from the domain `somedomain.com/wp-login` then it will show the authentication, if they do not, then it will not show it.

```
<if "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'somedomain.com/wp-login'">
    authname "member only"
    authtype basic
    authuserfile /home/taragurung/public_html/wp-admin/.passfile
    require valid-user
</if>
```

I hope this helps and as always, clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: Yes you understood the problem but the problem is the htaccess rule in the root is being implemented to the wordpress installed on the subdomain folder too. Tried your solution but didn't work

Comment: I get forbidden error with that rule added even on the main domain. @Lag